# wireshark can catch tcp package，but my socket can not recieve data

Tags: java, sockets, wireshark

Recently，I code a simple demo of socket to connect my server,which support sftp service.

```
Socket soc = new Socket("172.16.195.250",22); // ip:172.16.195.250 port:22
boolean isConnect = soc.isConnect(); //return true when project run
int b = 0;
InputStream is = soc.getInputStream();
while((b=is.read())!=-1){
    if(b==13){
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

The demo will run normally in many people's computers including mine，The ASCII of SSH version can be output on the console，but the demo block at the 'read()' running at some people's computer.

What my know is that the package of tcp has been arrived the net card,for the reason that I can catch the tcp package which from 172.16.195.250:22 to my client with tool named 'wireshark'.

My firewall has shutdowned,but I don't konw it is completely.

Some people who encountered such a situation can give me help ~
I am a newbie and my English is poor ，hoping u to understanding my problem. Thanks~

Comment: It's unclear what your question is. Is wireshark able to detect desired traffic but your code does not?

Comment: wireshark can catch tcp data but my java code can not read byte

Comment: The problem was caused by someone config my computer.It was solved when I patch